# Unable to locate the Bug

Tags: c, stack

I was recently on The Daily WTF when I came across this old [post](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Mister-Fixit.aspx).  In it the author mentions that one of the programmers changed this code:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{ 
  int x;
  char data_string[15];
  ...
  x = 2;
  strcpy(data_string,"data data data");
  ...
}
```

To this code:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
  int x = 2;
  char data_string[15] = "data data data";
  ...
}
```

The author goes on to mention:

> [the coder] changed every single variable to be initiated on the stack

For the life of me I cannot see how this change could be harmful, and I am worried that it is a lapse in my C knowledge.  What is the WTF?

Comment: DailyWTF jumped the shark entirely when Alex switched away from bite-sized code chunks and felt the necessity to write a whole article each time.

Comment: if you look at the comments in WTF you will see that nobody could see the issue either

Comment: When you see 1000+ files changed, just to do that, with no meaningful source control comment, it becomes a WTF in my book.

Comment: The fact that they changed the code when it didn't need changing is harmful. "The best code is no code".

Comment: possible duplicate of [I don't get this C/C++ Joke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420009/i-dont-get-this-c-c-joke)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the stack initialization was the problem.  He was supposed to be looking for a hard-to-find memory leak, but he decided to do the initialization change instead on thousands of C files.

Although, as [mentioned on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable), "uninitialized variables [are] a frequent cause of bugs".  You eliminate the potential for use of uninitialized variables if you take care of it at declaration.  But doing that conversion to a few thousand files probably wasn't the most efficient way to find and solve the real problem.

Comment: Actually I thought it was to prevent null-pointer usage which can be just as (or depending on the environment/OS) more insidious.  As well stack initialization helps with compiler optimizations making the code potentially faster. Depending on the intervening code complexity the assignment of x to 2 might not be done at allocation in the first example, where as you're all but guaranteed that to be the case in the second example/changed code.

Comment: It happens, sometimes the you just throw up your hands and fix everything that _might_ be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think the new code is better. Except I would have gone

```
  char data_string[] = "data data data";
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way this is worse is that it's possible that the older code never initialized (or used) the value in some code paths.

The other problem is this

```
char data_string[99] = "data data data";
```

Will initialize 99 characters rather than just the first 15.  which makes this

```
char data_strings[99] = "";
```

a lot more expensive than this

```
char data_strings[99];
data_strings[0] = 0;
```

Of course, if the buffer really only needs to be big enough to hold "data data data", 
then this is better

```
char data_string[] = "data data data";
```

But that makes you wonder whether it was ever necessary to copy the string into a stack variable at all.